# Which certificate for digital signing a visual studio integration extension(.vsix) with VSIXSignTool?

Tags: visual-studio, security, certificate, digital-signature, vsix

I want to add a digital signature to a Visual Studio Integration Extension (.vsix).

I followed the tutorial on the Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/signing-vsix-packages?view=vs-2019 which uses the VSIXSignTool.

The tutorial asks for a 'password protected certificate file'. I assume it is a code signing certificate in .pfx format. Right?

Apparently there are 2 kinds of code signing certificates:

- Regular one like: https://www.ssl.com/certificates/code-signing/
- Extended one like: https://www.ssl.com/certificates/ev-code-signing/

Which one works with the VSIXSignTool?

Answer (score 1):

VSIXSignTool works with the regular Code Signing Certificate just fine. Extended Validation is not required.